React-Native: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'
BUILD FAILED in 35s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-screens'. > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\Sreya\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125 did not have a source.properties file * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 35s

Please structure your question.


Go to android studio
Select SDK manager
Go to SDK tool tab
Tick the correct NDK version and install




In the android folder, in the build.gradle you need to mention the ndk version based on which version you have in your local. You can find those installed ndk version in this path. If you dont have that particular version as mentioned in the error, you need to download it, like mentioned by @Janitha Rasanga
C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk

Based on the version u have, you can update the build.gradle file



Which version of NDK do you have installed?
Is it specified in gradle.properties like this?
android {
    ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
}

And inside local.properties remove the following since it's deprecated and also conflicts with path:
ndk.dir=~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle

